# How to launch Chrome with explicit "hardware acceleration" setting?

Tags: linux, mac, google-chrome, terminal, chromium

There is an advanced setting in Google Chrome to toggle "hardware acceleration."

On a Mac, I want to be able to choose whether Chrome launches with this option on or off.

Any way to do this? (from the command line or AppleScript)

see: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags

and: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Command line switch `--disable-gpu`? Disables GPU hardware acceleration. If software renderer is not in place, then the GPU process won't launch

Comment: I tried `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-gpu` but if I then go into Settings, hardware acceleration is still on.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? May be related to this bug report [Issue 487115: Cannot disable GPU with "--disable-gpu" command line flag anymore](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487115), dated May 12, 2015. Marked as WontFix/Status unconfirmed (Oct 9, 2015)

Answer (score 2):

Your own answer is correct.  The only thing is that this only changes the setting for the current execution and does not affect your preferences.  I say this because I had issues running chrome with the setting enabled (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/7D3P84WKqew;context-place=forum/chrome), and the only way to get around it was to launch using the command yuo provided and then go into settings and disable it.

Answer (score 2):

For Chrome Canary

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome\ Canary --disable-gpu
```