# Launch GUI Application in WSL without XServer

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1703

I have installed windows 10 (b.1703) creators update recently and I am using ubuntu subsystem(**WSL**).There I have installed Visual Studio Code successfully. Problem is that any GUI elements required application cannot be launched(no GUI will be elements displayed reason may be WSL has no direct Graphic driver support).

[VSCOE Launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1K0Y.png)

[gEdit Launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5dsl.png)

I wanted to know How to provide graphic driver support to WSL in order to facilitate GUI applications? without installing 3rd party software such as *XMing-Xserver*, putty etc.

Else do we have any other mechanism to achieve it? Only modifying Ubuntu(Linux subsystem) side? Other than switching to **Windows 10 Insider preview** builds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowadays, the best option is to use a GUI in WSL is to install X Window software and connect to the Linux in WSL.

- You can install X Window software such as [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) or [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)
- There are many tutorials in the Internet using the above [VcXsrv](https://github.com/QMonkey/wsl-tutorial) and [MobaXterm](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/using-wsl-and-mobaxterm-to-create-a-linux-dev-environment-on-windows).

Note that the linux kernel in the WSL is not the same kernel you use in a bare-metal installation. The NVIDIA drivers do not work in WSL. If you are using Chrome or some window manager, you must configure them to run without using GPUs or Graphical acceleration.

- You may look at the answers in [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on WSL as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-wsl-as-of-2018).
- You may [run Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/988929/how-to-launch-chrome-with-explicit-hardware-acceleration-setting) with the `--disable-gpu` command line option.
- You may [configure the X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408582/how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration-in-linux) to disable the GPU extensions.
- You may [run the Gnome Session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832197/gnome-session-where-to-put-disable-acceleration-check) using the `--disable-acceleration-check`.

---

Recently, some developers created [LoWe - Linux on Windows extender](https://github.com/kpocza/LoWe). It is able to display the WSL UI without a third party X Window. It exports a Linux framebuffer and displays the UI in a Window. However, even using this option you cannot use the GPU neither.

- [Lowe](https://github.com/kpocza/LoWe) is an experimental implementation and it is not recommended for production.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need putty on local computer, because you have bash window.
You need X server (Xming...) to launch gedit.
Code Writer fails to launch at this moment.
Graphics not supported on WSL.
I use firefox with success.

Comment: me also successful on that :) .. but I think WSL still has not been facilitated with GPU driver support across Windows 10 boundary I guess.WSL still cannot carry out direct commnunication with graphic driver

Answer (score 1):

If you want GUI support in WSL with no 3rd party installers for graphics rendering, **[xWSL](https://github.com/DesktopECHO/xWSL)** seems to satisfy your requirement:

It downloads Ubuntu and installs/configures XRDP.
Upon completion of the installer it leaves an .RDP file on your desktop that you can just double-click to gain access to the Linux desktop (XFCE4 in this case.)

- xWSL Desktop Screenshot:

[image]